# Checking whether Atmega32 is dead

Tags: embedded, atmega

I know this may not be the correct place to post this, but how do I know if a certain chip is dead? My friend has this Atmega32 and he seems to have connected it to 9V battery for a minute maybe.. He's unsure about it, but I think the chip is damaged, So, is there any way to check if that is the case?

Comment: Move to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have read the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc2503.pdf) right! - the Electrical Characteristics section.

[image]

Even if it appears to work, parts of it may have failed, or stressed to the point that they will fail soon.  Any necessary over-voltage protection should ideally be designed into your circuit's power-supply design.

Answer (score 0):

Does it program? Do the I/O ports work? Did it emit magic smoke?

Likely, its dead.

Comment: Nope. Nothing, no smoke, its like cold..
Do you think 9V would burn it or will it have some sort of over-voltage protection?

Comment: "*like* cold", or *actually* cold? ;)

Comment: Processors contain ESD protection, but that is for transient microsecond events. Sustained 9V running through the body diodes and other logic gates will easily destroy some critical power supply and logic sections in the processor.